# Are all editions of "Joseph und seine Brüder" (by Thomas Mann) the same?

Tags: german-language, textual-history, thomas-mann, joseph-and-his-brothers

There are several editions of *Joseph and his brothers* (original German *Joseph und seine Brüder*). Do all of them contain the same text? Or did Thomas Mann make some "adjustments" for some publishers?

Comment: Hi, are you aware that *Joseph und seine Brüder* is a tetralogy and that volumes 2-4 do not represent revisions of the first volume? Do you have any specific editions in mind that you have come across?

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that (I read all of them three times). I've heard that there is a so called _Stockholmer Edition_ and a _Frankfurter Edition_. And maybe others. Do they just differ in typography / copyright / etc or are there substantial differences?